# can return statement be in initialization section of for loop?

Tags: java, for-loop

i heard somewhere that there can be any valid java statement in  initialization section of for loop.

when i tried to compile this code it gave me error illegal start of expression.
although i was expecting unreachable code error

what might be possible reason ?

thanks

```
class A
{

    public static void main(String args[]){

    int x=1;
    System.out.println("sds");


 }
public  int m1()
{



    int x=1;


    for(return 0;x==1;x++)
    ;
}
```

Comment: You heard wrong. The initialization section is either expressions separated by commas, or a variable declaration (potentially of more than one variable of the same type).

Comment: I can't think of a possible reason to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can't do that! You must have heard it wrong. The initialization of the for loop can contain variable declaration or assignment statements, seperated by commas, but not a return statement.

A return statement doesn't make *any* sense at all! You meant to write *initialization* in the *initialization* part of the for loop! And obviously you cannot initialize stuff with a `return`. Thus, it is not allowed.

As @Tunaki has said, the JLS states this very clearly. And I don't think you should break rules when you are coding. For example, you wouldn't want to change the constructor of a Singleton to public, although it still works. And in this for loop case, the founders of Java must have thought that some naughty people would write a return in a for loop initialization so they limited what you can write there.

Just remember, Don't do stuff that make no sense.

Comment: *"The initialization of the for loop can contain variable declaration or assignment statements..."* And several other kinds of statements, as shown by [Tunaki's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32668853/157247). Perhaps counter-intuitively, that includes calls to `void` methods.

Comment: hmmm, `void` methods can be doing some initialization too  {excluding `System.exit(0)` [:-) } (bit strange, but possible)

Answer (score 3):

The relevant part of the JLS is [section 14.14.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.1):

> BasicForStatement:
>
> `for ( [ForInit] ; [Expression] ; [ForUpdate] ) Statement`

With [`[ForInit]`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-ForInit) defined as:

> ForInit:
>
> `StatementExpressionList`
>
> `LocalVariableDeclaration`

where

> StatementExpressionList:
>
> `StatementExpression {, StatementExpression}`

and

> StatementExpression:
>
> `Assignment`
>   `PreIncrementExpression`
>   `PreDecrementExpression`
>   `PostIncrementExpression`
>   `PostDecrementExpression`
>   `MethodInvocation`
>   `ClassInstanceCreationExpression`

Note that `[ReturnStatement]` is not part of the allowed statements.